# pymongo atlas loadbalancer error ARM device

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I get a LoadBalancerSupportMismatch error accessing my online mongo database/cluster from an ARM device (Jetson Xavier) running ubuntu 18.04 jetson version that came with it. The code works on a normal x86 pc and is run using python 3.6 (I use 3.8 on the normal pc).
My code is straightforward. I anonymized parts of it.

```
self.online_client = MongoClient(
                    f"mongodb+srv://<user>:<passowrd>}@<dbname>.pkphq.mongodb.net/Xcontainers?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
self.cloud_coll = self.online_client[<dbname>][<collection>]
self.cloud_coll.insert_one(some_dict)
```

The error I get on the jetson is:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1319, in find_one
> for result in cursor.limit(-1):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1207, in next
> if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1100, in _refresh
> self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1816, in _ensure_session
> return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session
> server_session = self._get_server_session()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1802, in _get_server_session
> return self._topology.get_server_session()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 499, in get_server_session
> None)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 217, in _select_servers_loop
> (self._error_message(selector), timeout, self.description))
> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: The server is being accessed through a load balancer, but this driver does not have load balancing enabled, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'The server is being accessed through a load balancer, but this driver does not have load balancing enabled', 'code': 354, 'codeName': 'LoadBalancerSupportMismatch'}, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61ee9d768a646fd4a74f0849, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('containers-lb.pkphq.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=OperationFailure("The server is being accessed through a load balancer, but this driver does not have load balancing enabled, full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'The server is being accessed through a load balancer, but this driver does not have load balancing enabled', 'code': 354, 'codeName': 'LoadBalancerSupportMismatch'}",)>]>
> [INFO] [1643027861.848502]: No id to push measurement

My little journey at resolving the issue brought me here, as pretty much the only thing that seemed relevant: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/scala-driver-2-9-0-connection-fails-with-loadbalancersupportmismatch/126525/2 . So it appeared that the scala driver is not up to date. It seems I need to update it using sbt or maven: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.3/driver-scala/getting-started/installation/
I set up the hardware quite recently, and it's up to date, so a bit puzzling why the driver isn't then up to date.

Looking into the documentation of sbt and maven; it seems totally unrelated at worst and very complicated at best to get pymongo working properly again with mongo atlas.

Is there a better solution to make the load balancer issue go away, or get my driver up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, fixed it by upgrading pymongo to version 3.12, since [this document](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/) describes that as the minimum version for serverless clusters (which is my case)

Answer (score 0):

It seemed upgrading the cluster worked. I first used M0 - M2 cluster. Paying more for M10 somehow fixed the issue.